# .net How to show time in correct format?

Tags: .net, vsto, datetimepicker, cultureinfo, datetime-format

I have a VSTO Outlook add-in. This add-in shows winforms window with DateTimePicker contorl, it is used to choose time of day. I want to set time format similar to current Windows time format (like in clock from taskbar).

To do this I use following code:

```
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
```

In Windows Region and Language settings I have French in Format and Location and English in Keyboards and Languages.

As a result, in my form I see 7:00 instead of 19:00.

CurrentCulture, CurrentUICulture and InstalledUICulture returns "h:mm tt" shorttime format and culture name is en-US. 

My question is how to determine that Windows shows time in French format (HH:mm) and show time in DateTimePicker in this format?

--edit

When I run following code in separate console application

```
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern); 
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern); 
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern);
```

it returns

HH:mm

HH:mm:ss

dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss


In Outlook add-in similar code returns american format:


h:mm tt

h:mm:ss tt

dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt


Outlook is setup to use default Windows language (English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get time in Windows format, show form in separate thread. When showing it in Outlook thread it takes Outlook culture settings.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using custom formats, can't you use..

```
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
```

This should show the time in the correct format (i.e. the one selected by the user)

-- edit

What do you get if you run the following?

```
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern);
```

With my 'region and language' region set to 'French (France)' I get this.

```
HH:mm
HH:mm:ss
dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Thanks, Rich, it works. Is it possible to show time without seconds?

Comment: Just checking.. when you use your above customformat, you are also setting the 

    this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

Comment: yes, when I use customformat a set Format property to Custom. I have tried your solution and it works, but it shows time in format HH:mm:ss. Is it possible to hide seconds?